# Flexbox CSS rows not shrinking to fit inside container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox container with a fixed height and width, and some flex rows inside, each containing SVG objects.

When I add more SVGs to one row, the other SVGs in the row shrink to fit the container's width.
However, if I add more rows, they don't shrink to fit the container and instead overflow.

How can I prevent such behavior, and instead have the rows shrink properly to fit inside the container?

Example code (first row shows the horizontal shrinking; notice the two bottom rows overflow the div-page container):

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.row {
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
}

.div-page {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 420mm;
  padding: 10mm;
  overflow: hidden;
}

object {
  max-width: 25%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body style="width: 594mm;">
  <div class="div-page">
    <div class="row">
      <object data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Logo_test.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style=""></object>
      <object data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Logo_test.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style=""></object>
      <object data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Logo_test.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style=""></object>
      <object data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Logo_test.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style=""></object>
      <object data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Logo_test.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style=""></object>
      <object data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Logo_test.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style=""></object>
      <object data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Logo_test.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style=""></object>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <object data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Logo_test.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style=""></object>
      <object data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Logo_test.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style=""></object>
      <object data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Logo_test.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style=""></object>
      <object data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Logo_test.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style=""></object>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <object data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Logo_test.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style=""></object>
      <object data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Logo_test.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style=""></object>
      <object data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Logo_test.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style=""></object>
      <object data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Logo_test.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style=""></object>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <object data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Logo_test.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style=""></object>
      <object data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Logo_test.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style=""></object>
      <object data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Logo_test.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style=""></object>
      <object data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Logo_test.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style=""></object>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <object data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Logo_test.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style=""></object>
      <object data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Logo_test.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style=""></object>
      <object data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Logo_test.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style=""></object>
      <object data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Logo_test.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style=""></object>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by changing

```
.row {
  ...
  width: 100%
}
```

to

```
.row {
  ...
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
  min-height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `flex: 1` to the object element. It means it takes one portion of total width.

```
object {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: wrapping is not what I want, I want the rows to shrink their contents so that all rows fit inside the container

Comment: Try add `flex: 1` to the `object`